# How I can convert bash into sh

Tags: bash, expression, sh

I want to use regex expression, it works in bash, but in sh

```
str=9009
for i in *v[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt; do echo "$i";      
       if ! [[ "$i" =~ $str ]]; then rm "$i" ; fi    done
```

file name like this : mari_v9009.txt femme_v9009.txt mari_v9010.txt femme_v9010.txt, mari.txt, femme.txt

So I want to remove these files : mari_v9010.txt femme_v9010.txt

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
case $i in
    *"$str"* ) # do nothing
        ;;
    * ) rm "$i"
        ;;
esac
```

From your comments it sounds like you're actually asking for help with more than the regexp that's in your `if` statement. Try this:

```
str=9009
for i in ./*v[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt; do
    echo "$i" >&2
    if [ -e "$i" ]; then
        case $i in
            *"$str"* )
                echo "match for $str in $i" > &2
                ;;
            * ) echo "no match for $str in $i" >&2
                ;;
        esac
    else
         echo "no file name matching $i in directory" >&2
    fi
done
```

and change the `echo`s to whatever you like after testing.

Also consider not doing any of the above and doing this instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*v[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt' ! -name "*$str*" -exec echo rm {} \;
```

Comment: nope, beause it would be delete other files, like mari.txt, so I don't want it, I want to remove files contain *v[0-9][0-9]+([0-9]).txt and match with a number like 9009

Comment: nope, because it would be delete these files mari.txt, femme.txt, so I won't

Comment: No it would NOT delete those files. idk where you're coming from in saying that. The globbing in your loop will just select the files that match your globbing pattern `*v[0-9][0-9]+([0-9]).txt`. Or does that not do what you want either? You only asked about a regexp so that's what I'm trying to help you with, the regexp in the `if` not the globbing pattern in the `for`.

Comment: how I can use you code, I get rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory

Comment: Just replace the `if` you asked for help with with my code. You're having trouble with `if ! [[ "$i" =~ $str ]]; then rm "$i" ; fi`, right? So replace that with the code in my answer.

Comment: yes I did it, but when I use this code in debian package in rules files, I get *_v[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
rm: cannot remove *_v[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt’: No such file or directory, :(((((((((((((

Comment: for i in *_v[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt; do echo "$$i"; \
                case $$i in \
                        *"$(VERSION)"* ) # do nothing \
                                ;; \
                * ) rm "$$i" \
                        ;; \
                esac \
        done

Comment: There is no sh equivalent to `+([0-9])`. This case statement perfectly replaces this specific regex match though

Comment: but in debian packages it does not work :(, I will try with sed command

Comment: @locklockM no, the problem you're describing in the above comments has nothing to do with sed or with regexps or the problem you asked about in your question. Your globbing pattern just isn't matching on any files and so `$i` is being set to that specific string of characters. I updated my answer to show how to rewrite your whole script to be portable.